Convert the dollar amount value to a number format before sending it to Excel
In MuleSoft, convert the amount value into USD format like $3,567.00, but send the list of amount values to the Excel sheet as number so that Excel can calculate the total using the SUM() function
I have tried this logic in dataweave
fun usd(amount) = amount as String {format: “\$#,###.00}

Amount value send as String to excel(xlsx), please help logic how to send dollar amount value to excel to convert as number

Please explain what is the issue with that script. Are you saying that because it is a string you can use the value in calculations?

The issue is that calculations cannot be performed on string data in Excel. Is there any way to send the dollar amount value in a number format to Excel via dataweave?

DataWeave doesn't currently supports Excel formatting. It can output either:

Numbers without format
transform the number to a string applying a DataWeave format but the string can not be used as a number directly.

If outputting a String you could use Excel functions to extract the numeric value (see answers like How do you convert text like `'$71.4145` into a number you can do arithmetic with).
Another alternative would be instead of using DataWeave to use a Java library to generate Excel files with format. Search for such libraries and how to use them in Java. Then you can use Mule Java Module to invoke your Java code from a flow.

If I understand correctly, this will be: you input an amount then output is format $++amount formatted:
Maybe it can help:

"3567" as Number as String {format: "\$#,###.00"}

